# How can I stop downloads from Google Play when net balance is ending (or zero)?

Tags: google-play-store, 4.1-jelly-bean, downloading

In my SIM, the net balance is zero. But, the device shows that it is still downloading applications. Because of this, I am losing my main balance. Also, the battery is getting lower every 3 hours.

How can I stop this problem?

Comment: Please don't use ALL-CAPS next time. It is considered SHOUTING. :)

Comment: If you have a limited plan, I'd generally set the Playstore app to update on WiFi only. You can do so in its settings. That way it won't start any updates/downloads on its own when not on WiFi -- but you still can do so manually if needed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to disable the Google Play store from downloading apps that you have asked to download, however if you go into the Google Play app settings menu, you can enable the `Update on WiFi only` option - this will only let updates download when you are connected to WiFi.

You can also completely disable your mobile data connection by going to System Settings -> More -> Mobile Network -> Uncheck the mobile data checkbox.

This will stop your device from connecting to the mobile network data.